# How to call the properties of a HTML Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

> How can i change the property to editable Text box?   for instance
>   when I click a button the read only property will change to editable.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SName, new { @readonly="readonly"})
```

> Thanks to @von v. here's the solution below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SName, new { @readonly="readonly"})
     <button value="New" id="btnConfirm">New</button>

<script>
     $("#btnConfirm").click(function(){
     $("#SName").removeAttr('readonly');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in jquery:

```
$("#button_id").click(function() {
    $("#Sname").removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

UPDATE:

> having several `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SName, new {
>   @readonly="readonly"}) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FName, new {
>   @readonly="readonly"}) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LName, new {
>   @readonly="readonly"})` How can I call it on the javascript function.

You mean like this:

```
$("#button_id").click(function() {
    $("#Sname").removeAttr('readonly');
    $("#LName").removeAttr('readonly');
    $("#FName").removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

Comment: I tried the submit type button and button tag ,but it's not firing.

Comment: Are you referencing the correct button? Did you mean the click event of the button is not firing? Or is the textbox still read-only? Show you code/html please.

Comment: The js function is not firing when you click the button and the textbox is still readonly                                                              Here's the code:                                                               
               '

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#btnConfirm").click(function () {
      $("#SName").removeAttr('readonly');
    });
</script>

<table>
     <tr>
     <td class="style1">
     @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.SName)</td>
<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SName, new { @readonly="readonly"})</td>
</tr>
<button name="btnConfirm" value="New">New</button>
<input type="submit" value="New" name="btnConfirm"/>
</table>`

Comment: You should have added the code in your question :)  Anyway, assign an id to the button, would be better to do it that way.

Comment: Oh Sorry :D  
Anyways thank you very much, it's now working  :)

Comment: And instead of showing the answer to your question, you should accept (and/or upvote) the question to your answer. Remember this is a Q&A site as much as a wiki site ;)

Comment: _Can I ask a question here in comment box?_ anyways
if I have more than one HTML Helpers, how can pass it on script (in the best way)?

Comment: You mean several submit buttons? If yes and it seems that it's a different scenario, and that we are beginning to have a long chat here, then I suggest you ask another question.

Comment: No, but having several 
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SName, new { @readonly="readonly"})`
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FName, new { @readonly="readonly"})`
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LName, new { @readonly="readonly"})`
How can I call it on the javascript function.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: See updated answer, please ask another question if that's not what you meant. We really should not discuss this long in a single question :)